# Restoring the default itemRenderer for combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drop-down-menu, combobox

What i need to do is let the user restore the default itemRenderer after they put in a custom one.
It works for List, but not when i try to do it for combobox and dropdownList. When i try open the combobox with a resetted defaultItemRenderer then the items are not shown (but i can still select items with the arrow keys).
This is how i do it:

```
defaultItemRenderer = component.itemRenderer;
component.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MyListItemRenderer);
```

...some time later when the user says it...

```
component.itemRenderer = defaultItemRenderer;
component.validateNow();
```

As i said, for List it works like a charm, but not for combobox.

P.S.  im refering to spark components

Comment: Which combobox? Spark? MX? For the mx, you can do comboBox.dropdown.invalidateList() and it should rebuild it.

Comment: Spark combobox and dropDownList, i will update my question